# How to Develop laravel app without internet connection

Tags: php, laravel

In our company intranet we are not provided with internet connection due to security reasons. Is it possible to develop laravel application in such an environment? Is it possible to download laravel and all dependencies in a local server and serve the same to the development team?

Comment: you WILL have to download all dependency in order to run a `Laravel` development locally. If it's a big project you will definitely want to use a version control like git. So for that you will need internet (for git). Also sometimes you might need to install some `Laravel` packages for application, internet will be required for that too. Other than that you can setup local server `(Laragon for windows, MAMP for mac, Valet for Linux)` and develop your application locally.

Answer (score -1):

yes, but first u need to make main (skeleton) Laravel project with all your dependencies(with internet), and after just make copy of skeleton project(without internet). Or u can try to install installer https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#installing-laravel